# Random characters inside URL with vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, loops, random, webrequest

I'm doing a webrequest and need to input static + random characters (numbers and letters) inside every url request:

```
Dim postData1 As String = "http://www.xxx.com/......" & rdm & "xxxyyyzzz.htm"
Dim postReq1 As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(postData2), HttpWebRequest)

Dim postData2 As String = "http://www.xxx.com/......" & rdm & "xxxyyyzzz.htm"
Dim postReq2 As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(postData2), HttpWebRequest)

etc
```

The requests (6 on total) keep looping. Here's the code I'm using for random:

```
Dim chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
            Dim random = New Random()
            Dim result = New String(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 3).[Select](Function(s) s(random.[Next](s.Length))).ToArray())

            Dim rdmpart = "x1y2z3"
            rdm = rdmpart & result
```

I need a sequence of urls looping and generating a new rdm on each request. How's that possible? Whenever I call "rdm" it gives me the same response. Thanks in advance.

---

Here's the solution:

Finally worked! This was driving me insane :)
Here's what I did, based on Frito's answer:

```
Public Shared Function rdm() As String

        Static random As New Random()
        Dim chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
        Dim result = New String(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 3).[Select](Function(s) s(random.[Next](s.Length))).ToArray())

        Dim rdmpart = "x1y2z3"
        rdm = rdmpart & result

    End Function
```

And called with a simple "rdm()" Yeay!

Comment: How quickly are you calling this code?  Move the New Random() outside the call - if you call that too quickly, you will be recreating the Random object with the same seed.

Comment: @user1488379 You don't have to edit your title to save "Solved" or copy and paste the accepted answer into your question.  Anyone on the main page can see what questions have an accepted answer and while viewing the question it is clear which answer was accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm very rusty on VB but you may want to try something like this...

```
Public Class CustomRandomGenerator

    Private Shared myRandom as New Random()

    Public Shared Function GenerateRandomString() As String

        Dim chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
        Dim result = New String(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 3).[Select](Function(s) s(random.[Next](s.Length))).ToArray())

        Dim rdmpart = "x1y2z3"
        rdm = rdmpart & result

        Return result
    End Function

End Class
```

The "Private Shared myRandom as New Random()" is mainly what you're looking for. As "Chachi" attempted to explain, you need to have **only one** random generator. This is because the Random object is a function that gives sudo-random values on it's "Next()" call. When you call the Random constructor it uses the systems current time to provide a seed value to it's internal function.

Depending on the version of .Net that you're using, the Random() constructor will either always seed with the system time **or** "0". If you're always getting the same result each time you run the code then change the "New Random()" section to something like "New Random(System.DateTime.Now.Ticks)" and you should be good. :-)

Lastly, you'll call this in your code by using "CustomRandomGenerator.GenerateRandomString()". I figured that might need mention if you're not familiar with "shared" methods / variables.

Comment: I can't believe it finally worked! I had to do minor changes (will create an answer with details) but your codes saved me. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Edited the original post with details, thanks again my friend!

Answer (score 1):

try this：

random use the same time seed.

so，use ONLY ONE random object and init it ONCE.

sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you were creating a `New Random()` each time you wanted to generate a random URL, which isn't the right way to use it (it uses the current time as a seed, so if your code runs fast enough, it'll generate the same random number sequence each time).  Here's an example that should work:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
    Dim random = New Random()

    For i = 0 To 10
        Dim result = New String(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 3).[Select](Function(s) s(random.[Next](s.Length))).ToArray())
        Dim rdmpart = "x1y2z3"
        Dim rdm = rdmpart & result

        Dim postData As String = "http://www.xxx.com/......" & rdm & "xxxyyyzzz.htm"
        Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(postData), HttpWebRequest)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but still gives me the same random number on each run thru :( I need it to be like this:

request1 = x1y2z3a49
request2 = x1y2z3i3s
request3 = x1y2z348s
request1 = x1y2z3gd2
request2 = x1y2z36gd
request3 = x1y2z3j56
etc etc...